# How to calculate probit in C++

Tags: c++, statistics, sas

I'm converting some [SAS code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAS_%28software%29) into C++ but currently stuck on how to calculate the [probit](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000245933.htm) function.

I believe I've found the probit formula (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probit) but my statistics knowledge is a little rusty. So basically I need someone to convert this to C++, or tell me if there is the same method under another name.

Comment: i believe boost has what you're looking for built in (see here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/math/doc/sf_and_dist/html/math_toolkit/dist/stat_tut/weg/normal_example/normal_misc.html for a worked example)

Comment: This will be for mobile apps (android and iPhone). The boost library seems to be quite large.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the boost math library and the definition of probit you found on the wikipedia article I came up with the following. No warranties here :-)

```
#include <boost/math/special_functions/erf.hpp>

namespace bm = boost::math;

template<typename T>
T probit(T p)
{
    T root_2 = sqrt(2);

    return root_2 * bm::erf_inv(2*p-1);
}

int main()
{
    double val = 0.9;
    double res = probit(val);
}
```

Comment: This will be for mobile apps (android and iPhone). The boost library seems to be quite large hmm...

Comment: You don't need the whole library - it's very modular. And a static link to just the functions you need will significantly limit the damage.

Comment: Ok awesome. I'll have a look into that.